# What is a clean, simple and recommended way to implement forms in rails with Vue.js components

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js, vue-component, ruby-on-rails-6

With different articles around the web for rails forms with vue and a flurry of approaches it seems there is a lot of confusion on what the most elegant solution is. My primary concern was how to pass data/model object from the rails view to vue component, but I can use other best practises as well. I'd prefer sticking with rails for as much functionality as possible and use Vue only for javascript goodness (in my current form it's just client side validations for now).

Here's what I have until now (I am also using [Buefy](https://buefy.org/) as a component library):

```
# app/views/organizations/new.html.erb

<%= form_with(model: @organization, local: true) do |form| %>
  <organization-create-new-form
    :data=<%= { organization: @organization }.to_json %>>
  </organization-create-new-form>
<% end %>
```

I kept the `form_with` tag in rails view so that I don't need to handle the CSRF token part in vue component.

```
# organizationCreateNewForm.vue

<template>
<section class="hero is-bold is-fullheight">
  <div class="hero-body">
    <div class="container has-text-centered">
      <h1 class="title">
        Create a new workspace for your organization
      </h1>
      <h2 class="subtitle">
        Enter your organization name below
      </h2>
      <div class="columns">
        <div class="column is-half is-offset-one-quarter">
          <b-field>
            <b-input placeholder="Organization Name" size="is-large"></b-input>
          </b-field>

          <b-button type="is-primary" size="is-medium" native-type="submit">Continue</b-button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      organization: JSON.parse("still need to figure out how to get data here from rails view")
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

```
# application.js where `content` is the id of my top level div in my rails layout

import TurbolinksAdapter from 'vue-turbolinks'
import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue.esm'
import Buefy from 'buefy'
import '../stylesheets/application.scss'
import Vuelidate from 'vuelidate'

Vue.use(TurbolinksAdapter)
Vue.use(Buefy)
Vue.use(Vuelidate)

document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', () => {
  const app = new Vue({
    el: '#content',
  })
})
```

Things I want to figure out:

- What's the best way to pass data/object from rails view to component. A lot of online tutorials use `getElementById` and then read the data from attribute and parse it in their application.js file when initializing the component. What are the best practices here when I want to do it inside a component? Where (at what trigger) does the parsing happen inside a component?
- Any preferred way of abstracting all the json conversion (in rails view) and parsing (in vue component) for each form into something simple?
- I still want to submit the form as a regular rails form (and not ajax) which I think will happen automatically in the current structure. With turbolinks normal form submission looks pretty smooth.

Does someone use a minimal reusable setup to implement rails forms using vue components. It will be really helpful if you can share the same! Thanks for the help!